# How would you have an object observe/subscribe to itself to watch a certain field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my observer I'm trying to write a method for a product to "look at itself" and then find the same product with the `:price` field being the only difference. In other words, I'm trying to notify a user if they subscribe to product of lower prices.

Here is my Products table:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.string  :name
  t.decimal :price
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :store_id
  t.boolean :watch_price
end
```

And then I have my observer for it:

```
class ProductObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_update(product)
    if product.watch_price

    end
  end
end
```

So if the boolean `:watch_price` is true then a user has subscribed to that product. I put it in the `after_update(product)` because I want the users to be able to select the `watch_price` checkbox and then it does a Cron job instantly and then every hour after that on the database.

The issue I'm having is making a Product evaluate itself and search for Products that are just the same with the only difference being the `:price` field. How would this be done?

Thanks in advance, a newbie could use some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a subscription mechanism/relationship.  A lot could be done to improve the performance of the example below as well as make it more modular, but you should get the idea.

#### app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

#### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :products, :through => :subscriptions

  def notify_of_price_drop(product, original_price)
    # notify somehow
  end
end
```

#### app/models/subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  # be sure to add snapshot_price field to the subscriptions table in your migration
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

#### app/models/product_observer.rb

```
class ProductObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_update(product)
    product.subscriptions.each do |subscription|
      if subscription.snapshot_price < product.price
        subscription.user.notify_of_price_drop(product, subscription.snapshot_price)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need a HMT watched_products model to track which users are tracking which products.  In that model you could keep an attribute of the price they watched at and the product name.

You can use that model to hourly search for products that have a lower price with the same name and then notify the user.

```
# Model
class WatchedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  # attributes name, price
end

# CRON/Rake task
for watched_product in WatchedProduct.all
 for product in Product.find_by_name(watched_product.name)
   if watched_product.price > product.price
      # notify user
      # update the new watched price of the cheaper product
   end
 end
end
```

Obviously could be optimised more but you get the idea.

You prob want to expire watched products with another cron job.